# PowerShell Use Common Folder & Text From Files There

Tags: share, powershell-3.0

I have a search that I need to run on multiple file shares, and I am trying to setup my code so that I have to enter in the search folder name as few times as possible.

I have a folder called: **C:\Server1** with 2 text documents in there to import, and I want to export a number of documents into that same folder. Hence, why I want to set the folder to save into once as a variable.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$ShareFolderToUse = "C:\Server1\"
```

And to try and use that information:

```
$ShareDrivePath = $ShareFolderToUse + "ShareDrivePath.txt"
```

That last line is trying to set the variable to be the contents of the text file "C:\Server1\ShareDrivePath.txt"

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get-content` cmdlet to read the file content :

```
$ShareDrivePath=get-content (join-path $ShareFolderToUse "ShareDrivePath.txt")
```